# Combine separate armatures

Tags: rigging, objects, armature

On the right side under scene I have a couple different armatures like
armature.001 and armature.002 and bone. I was wondering how I make these all one object[image]
I'm trying to parent bone 4 to the neck bone but it wont work. I'm guessing because of these separate armatures.

Comment: See the answer to the linked question, your problem seems like a simpler case of the same thing (joining rigs/armatures)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is select one armature, <kbd>shift</kbd> select the other one, and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join them.

Then <kbd>shift</kbd> select the two meshes that go with the armatures, and join them too.

Then all you have to do is select the mesh, <kbd>shift</kbd> select the armature, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. Then select the armature deform option.